# AppleScript to open a Finder window in every desktop

Tags: finder, applescript

I have 2 monitors and 2 desktops (Spaces) in each of them. I want to open a Finder window for each of the desktops, so 4 in total.

I mapped the Spaces in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd> in Settings, and I am using Automator to switch Spaces and open a new Finder window.

The problem is that it only works for the main monitor. It iterates correctly the first 2 Spaces, and opens a Finder window, but then it does not focus on the 3rd & 4th Spaces in my second monitor. So it ends up opening 3 Finder widows in my 2nd space.

```
Applescript
on run {input, parameters}
    
(* Your script goes here *)
    
    repeat with keycd from 18 to 21
        
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application "System Events" to key code keycd using control down
    end tell
        
    delay 0.2
        
    tell application "Finder"
        make new Finder window
        get insertion location
    end tell
        
    delay 0.2
        
end repeat
    
    
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "System Events" to key code 18 using control down
end tell
    
return input
end run
```